# Logged in to paypal sandbox, on pay with paypal page can't log in

Tags: wordpress, paypal, sandbox, woocommerce

I am logged into my Sandbox account in a different tab, and from my store I click proceed with paypal.. it takes me to a pay with paypal page that I set up in my sandbox.. but once I try to log in to make a mock payment it says "Please check your email address and password and try again"

I am trying to login using the paypal account which I am already logged in as, saying it's not working.. and I even try another paypal account.. still says it's wrong details.

I have gotten my client ID and secret, but I am not sure where I need to put them.

I am using Woocommerce WP Plugin

I am checking out [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token) on paypal developer site but am not sure how to do this as a lot of features are facilitated by WP

thanks to anyone that can help

Answer (score 3):

I played with this a little more because I needed to do some testing and I figure it out.
Once you login to your paypal develop account, first thing you need to do in paypal sandbox is click on Applications -> Sandbox Accounts
You will see a business account listed. Copy that email, go back to you woocommerce Paypal payment setting page and put that email as Paypal Email and Receiver Email.
Then go back to Sandbox Accounts and create a new account. This one will be Personal account.  This personal account you will use as a customer.

Hope that helps
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.  I tried different settings accounts, does not work in sandbox. So what I did was setup a $1 transaction, set the store to live, and did the test that way, and it worked. Except I can't figure out why the customer order is always placed on hold after successful transaction

Comment: It should be set to `Processing`. Did you get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the plugin code and change the paypal URL to sandbox.paypal.com instead of just paypay.com.

Wordpress Admin Panel -> Plugins -> Editor
Select your plugin in the upper right, click Select Button
Typically you can find the

```
"<form action=.."
```

call and change the URL there unless your plugin stashed the URL into a variable first, in which case hopefully it's at the top and easy to find/replace.

Don't forget to change that back when you're done!

- Mitch

Comment: Thanks Mitch, this worked perfectly for me, thanks!


*Really wish they would include this in the documentation or something somewhere

Comment: Glad that helped, vote it up as 'useful' if that solved your problem so it's easier to find the 'accepted' answer.  I modified my answer, I realized my full answer (the code snippet for instance) wasn't showing properly

Comment: When I did this I got an error that post method is not supported.What should I do now?